# MAX value in SQL

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, sql, personal-geodatabase

I have used a variation of this sql statement successfully in the past but can't get it to work now. I have a table named "RS_Event_All_NE_25_Weekdays" in a personal geodatabase running on arcmap 10.2. I have a field called ROUTE_ID and another field called TRIP_NUM. Every record is an event that happens on a route. The TRIP_NUM gives the number of the trip the route is on when the event occurs. Each route can do up to 3 trips in a day. Most routes will do 2 trips but some do 3 and some do only 1.

I want to use a sql statement to select all the events for each route that happens during the last trip.

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT [TRIP_NUM] IN (SELECT MAX( [TRIP_NUM] ) FROM [RS_Event_All_NE_25_Weekdays] GROUP BY [ROUTE_ID] )
```

This gave a general syntax error. I have read another post on here using the nested sql expession with the MAX clause. I copied that syntax and replaced the field and table names and still got a syntax error.

Comment: A *personal geodatabase* uses the SQL implementation if Microsoft Access. I doubt that is valid syntax. Only the subselect would be needed.

Comment: Tried this and still getting invalid syntax error: SELECT MAX ([TRIP_NUM])  FROM [RS_Event_All_NE_25_Weekdays] GROUP BY [ROUTE_ID]

Comment: Try: [TRIP_NUM] IN
  (SELECT MAX [TRIP_NUM]
   FROM [RS_Event_All_NE_25_Weekdays]
   WHERE [RS_Event_All_NE_25_Weekdays.ROUTE_ID] = [AnotherTable.ROUTE_ID])